# How to clear form value via JavaScript? some of the value resetting some not, why is that?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I would like to clear my from value by reset button and submit button but some of them working with my function some doesn't.

```js
function emptyValidate() {

  var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  var city = document.getElementById('city').value;
  var state = document.getElementById('state');
  var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
  var cnumber = document.getElementById('cnumber').value;
  var month = document.getElementById('month');
  var year = document.getElementById('year');

  if (fname == "") {
    alert("First Name is Required");
  } else if (lname == "") {
    alert("Last Name is Required");
  } else if (phone == "") {
    alert("Phone Number is Required");
  } else if (isNaN(phone) || phone.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
    alert("Enter numeric value in phone number")
  } else if (phone.length < 5) {
    alert("enter 10 digits phone number");
  } else if (email == "" || email.indexOf("@") <= 0) {
    alert("enter valid email address");
  } else if (address == "") {
    alert("Address is Required");
  } else if (city == "") {
    alert("City is Required");
  } else if (isNaN(zip) || zip.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
    alert("Enter numeric value in zip code");
  } else if (zip.length < 5) {
    alert("enter 5 digits zip code");
  } else if (isNaN(cnumber) || cnumber.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
    alert("Enter numeric value in Card Number")
  } else if (cnumber.length < 13) {
    alert("enter 13 digits card number");
  } else {
    alert('Thank You for Signup as a New Member');
    window.location = "http://www.youtube.com";
  }
}

function clearFunc() {
  document.getElementById('fname').value = "";
  document.getElementById('lname').value = "";
  document.getElementById('phone').value = "";
  document.getElementById('email').value = "";
  document.getElementById('address').value = "";
  document.getElementById('city').value = "";
  document.getElementById('state').reset();
  document.getElementById('zip').value = "";
  document.getElementById('cnumber').value = "";
  document.getElementById('month');
  document.getElementById('year');
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(image/g\ \(6\).jpg);
}

table,
td {
  padding: 0px 20px 8px 20px;
}

.container {
  border: 4px rgb(122, 117, 116) groove;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-right: 700px;
  margin-left: 650px;
  margin-bottom: 105px;
  background-color: rgb(223, 230, 230);
}

.btn {
  font-size: 110%;
  font-weight: 100;
  background: #DD4A5A;
  border-color: #DD4A5A;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #9b323f;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #990819;
}

h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Signup</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="image/gym logo.JPG" alt="Gold Gym" width="120" height="85"></a>
  </div>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 style="margin-left: 45px;">Member Information</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fname"><b style="color: red;">*</b>First Name:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="fname">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lname"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Last Name:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="lname">
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Phone Number:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="phone">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Email Address:</label> <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="email">
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Address:</label> <br><input type="text" size="51" class="form-control input-sm" id="address">
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="city"><b style="color: red;">*</b>City:</label> <br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="city">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="zip"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Zip:</label> <br><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="zip">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td width="230px">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="city"><b style="color: red;">*</b>State:</label><br>
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm">
                  <option value="NY">NY</option>
                  <option value="AK">AK</option>
                  <option value="AR">AR</option>
                  <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                  <option value="CA">CA</option>
                  <option value="CO">CO</option>
                  <option value="CT">CT</option>
                  <option value="DC">DC</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              <h1>Billing Information</h1>
              <input type="checkbox" id="check"> Billing information is same as member information.
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="border:1px solid #adadad;">
            <td>
              <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:10px;">
                <label for="cnumber"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Card Number:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cnumber">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td width="230px">
              <label for="city"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Expiration Date:</label>
              <div class="form-inline">
                <select class="col-md-6 form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-right:10px">
                  <option value="">Month</option>
                  <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
                  <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
                  <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
                  <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
                  <option value="May">May</option>
                  <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
                  <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
                  <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
                  <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
                  <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
                  <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
                </select>
                <select class="col-md-6 form-control form-control-sm">
                  <option value="">Year</option>
                  <option value="2021">2021</option>
                  <option value="2022">2022</option>
                  <option value="2023">2023</option>
                  <option value="2024">2024</option>
                  <option value="2025">2025</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:20px;">
              <input type="submit" value="Signup" class="btn" onclick="emptyValidate()" />
              <input type="reset" value="Clear Entries" onclick="clearFunc()" id="res" class="btn" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <footer class="footer-background">
    <p class="text-footer">
      &#169;&nbsp<a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none">Gold Gym</a>&nbsp2021
    </p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and remove all of the unnecessary code.  We only need to see the code **segment** that directly pertains to your question.  Then, explain what parts of that code segment aren't working as you expect.  "Some of them working and some don't" tells us nothing about what isn't working.

Comment: there is no form in your page, your question does not make sense

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Signup</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <style>
        body{
            background-image: url(image/g\ \(6\).jpg);
        }
        table,
        td {

            padding: 0px 20px 8px 20px;

        }

        .container {
            border: 4px rgb(122, 117, 116) groove;
            margin-top: 150px;
            margin-right: 700px;
            margin-left: 650px;
            margin-bottom: 105px;
            background-color: rgb(223, 230, 230);
            

        }


        .btn {
            font-size: 110%;
            font-weight: 100;
            background: #DD4A5A;
            border-color: #DD4A5A;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #9b323f;
            color: #fff;
            margin-top: 10px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }

        .btn:hover {
            background: #990819;
        }
        h1{
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="image/gym logo.JPG" alt="Gold Gym" width="120" height="85"></a>
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <form id="form" class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <h1 style="margin-left: 45px;">Member Information</h1>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <table>

                    <tr>

                        <td>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="fname"><b style="color: red;">*</b>First Name:</label> <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control input-sm" id="fname">

                            </div>

                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="lname"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Last Name:</label> <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control input-sm" id="lname">

                            </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="phone"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Phone Number:</label> <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control input-sm" id="phone">

                            </div>

                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="email"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Email Address:</label> <input
                                    type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="email">

                            </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td colspan="2">

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="address"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Address:</label> <br><input type="text"
                                    size="51" class="form-control input-sm" id="address">

                            </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="city"><b style="color: red;">*</b>City:</label> <br>

                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="city">

                            </div>


                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                <label for="zip"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Zip:</label> <br><input type="text"
                                    class="form-control input-sm" id="zip">

                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td width="230px">

                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                <label for="city"><b style="color: red;">*</b>State:</label><br>

                                <select class="form-control form-control-sm">

                                    <option value="NY">NY</option>

                                    <option value="AK">AK</option>

                                    <option value="AR">AR</option>

                                    <option value="AZ">AZ</option>

                                    <option value="CA">CA</option>

                                    <option value="CO">CO</option>

                                    <option value="CT">CT</option>

                                    <option value="DC">DC</option>

                                </select>

                            </div>


                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td colspan="2">

                            <h1>Billing Information</h1>

                            <input type="checkbox" id="check"> Billing information is same as member information.

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr style="border:1px solid #adadad;">

                        <td>

                            <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:10px;">

                                <label for="cnumber"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Card Number:</label>

                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cnumber">

                            </div>

                        </td>

                        <td width="230px">

                            <label for="city"><b style="color: red;">*</b>Expiration Date:</label>

                            <div class="form-inline">

                                <select class="col-md-6 form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-right:10px">

                                    <option value="">Month</option>

                                    <option value="Jan">Jan</option>

                                    <option value="Feb">Feb</option>

                                    <option value="Mar">Mar</option>

                                    <option value="Apr">Apr</option>

                                    <option value="May">May</option>

                                    <option value="Jun">Jun</option>

                                    <option value="Aug">Aug</option>

                                    <option value="Sep">Sep</option>

                                    <option value="Oct">Oct</option>

                                    <option value="Nov">Nov</option>

                                    <option value="Dec">Dec</option>

                                </select>

                                <select class="col-md-6 form-control form-control-sm">

                                    <option value="">Year</option>

                                    <option value="2021">2021</option>

                                    <option value="2022">2022</option>

                                    <option value="2023">2023</option>

                                    <option value="2024">2024</option>

                                    <option value="2025">2025</option>

                                </select>

                            </div>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:20px;">

                            <input type="submit" value="Signup" class="btn" onclick="emptyValidate()" />
                            <input type="reset" value="Clear Entries" onclick="clearFunc()" id="res" class="btn" />


                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </table>

            </div>

        </div>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function emptyValidate() {

            var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;

            var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;

            var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;

            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

            var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

            var city = document.getElementById('city').value;

            var state = document.getElementById('state');

            var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;

            var cnumber = document.getElementById('cnumber').value;

            var month = document.getElementById('month');

            var year = document.getElementById('year');

            if (fname == "") {

                alert("First Name is Required");

            }

            else if (lname == "") {

                alert("Last Name is Required");

            } else if (phone == "") {

                alert("Phone Number is Required");

            }

            else if (isNaN(phone) || phone.indexOf(" ") != -1) {

                alert("Enter numeric value in phone number")

            }

            else if (phone.length < 5) {

                alert("enter 10 digits phone number");

            }

            else if (email == "" || email.indexOf("@") <= 0) {

                alert("enter valid email address");

            }

            else if (address == "") {

                alert("Address is Required");

            }

            else if (city == "") {

                alert("City is Required");

            }

            else if (isNaN(zip) || zip.indexOf(" ") != -1) {

                alert("Enter numeric value in zip code");

            } else if (zip.length < 5) {

                alert("enter 5 digits zip code");

            }

            else if (isNaN(cnumber) || cnumber.indexOf(" ") != -1) {

                alert("Enter numeric value in Card Number")

            }

            else if (cnumber.length < 13) {

                alert("enter 13 digits card number");

            }
            else {
                alert('Thank You for Signup as a New Member');
                window.location = "http://www.youtube.com";
            }

        }
        function clearFunc() {
        document.getElementById("form").reset();
        }
    </script>


    <footer class="footer-background">
        <p class="text-footer">
            &#169;&nbsp<a href="index.html" style="text-decoration:none">Gold Gym</a>&nbsp2021
        </p>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

use `document.getElementById("myform").reset();` to rest the form!

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as correct.